# Improving Script Function in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am fairly new at using scripts and honestly don't know much. I got this script off the internet and wondering if there is a way to improve it further (speed wise, since I noticed it takes about 6-8secs to finish the script). It is a data entry system that I introduced in an online game I play to facilitate pay records in game. Appreciate your help!

```js
//Function to validate the entry made by user in Add Pay
function validateEntry() {
  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shAddPay = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Add Pay");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Validating Pay Slot (GMT)
  if (shAddPay.getRange("C3").isBlank() == true) {
    ui.alert("Please enter Pay Slot.");
    shAddPay.getRange("C3").activate();
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Amount
  if (shAddPay.getRange("C5").isBlank() == true) {
    ui.alert("Please enter Amount.");
    shAddPay.getRange("C5").activate();
    return false;

  }

  //Validating Employee Paid
  if (shAddPay.getRange("C7").isBlank() == true) {
    ui.alert("Please enter Employee Paid.");
    shAddPay.getRange("C7").activate();
    return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

I tried to search more about batch operations but I can't really get it (I have zero background at scripts not until 2hrs ago).

Comment: Please learn how to [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: The `ui` interface _can_ be slow to load. What if you skipped the script altogether and used conditional formatting in C3, C5 and C7. You could test "IF BLANK" and colour, say, "red" if blank and "green" if not.

Comment: OTOH, if you _really_  want some script practice, try to create a single `IF`.